# Visual Studio 2010 - Dictionary Not found but it exists

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, resourcedictionary

Well, I´m developing a wpf application and I got a strange error on design time. This is the code of a wpf form:

```
<Window x:Class="ViewLayer.Frm_EnrollWaitingList"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Frm_EnrollWaitingList" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" Height="390" Width="410"
        WindowStyle="None"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary/WaitingListDictorionary.xaml"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="rectangle1" Stroke="{x:Null}" Fill="#FF8C90AD" Opacity="0.95" />
        <Button Style="{DynamicResource CommonButton}" Content="Salir" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="166,234,0,0" Name="btn_close" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="180" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The problem starts here:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary/WaitingListDictorionary.xaml"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

The `ResourceDictionary` exits and in execution time it works perfectly. But at design time sometime when a want to modify the form in visual studio designer i get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundException An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary "Dictionary/WaitingListDictorionary.xaml".


Unable to find the specified file.
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Platform.ViewProducerBase.Microsoft.Expression.DesignModel.DocumentModel.IDocumentRootResolver.GetDocumentRoot(String path)
   at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.WPF.InstanceBuilders.ResourceDictionaryInstanceBuilder.ProvideResourceDictionary(IInstanceBuilderContext context, DocumentCompositeNode resourceDictionaryReferenceNode, IDocumentRoot& relatedRoot)
```

And I can not edit the form with the designer.

Any idea? I repeat on execution time I have no problems.

Comment: Did you add the xaml-file to your solution?

Comment: 1) Is your WaitingListDictionary.xaml file locatined in a Dictionary folder? (if so, try moving the file to the root folder of the project, the same folder as your Window.xaml); 2) Are you using VS 2010 SP1? (if so, try unisntalling SP1);

Comment: Just a side note: DynamicResource  are resolved during the runtime and are generally slower than StaticResources, so if the style is defined in your dictionary I would use StaticResources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Source` property is relative, and you window appears to be in the ViewLayer directory, so the `Dictionary` folder must also be in the ViewLayer directory if you use

```
Source="Dictionary/WaitingListDictorionary.xaml".
```

If the Dicionary folder is at the root level, try

```
Source="/Dictionary/WaitingListDictorionary.xaml".
```

You can also use a pack:// URL.

Answer (score -1):

I could figure it out!

There was an error on the `ResourceDictionary` I was trying to use. I fixed it, and voila! Everything works like a charm.